# Function call with array index

Tags: c++

I came across with a statement with function call and as well as array index in the kind of code mentioned below .In this the statement s=o.init()[-1] is returning value of a1[0].
I am not cleared with the concept of how it is working, what this statement o.init()[-1] will do ?, i know 0.init() will give a call to function but what does [-1] specify?
Pls help to solve this query?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class a
{
  char a1[1000];

  public:
  a()
 {
    a1[0]='a';
 }
  char* init()
  {
     cout<<"value of a1 is"<<a1<<endl;
     return a1+1;
  }
};

int main()
{
   a o;
  char s;
  s=o.init()[-1];


cout<<"value of s  is"<<s<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of the *method* is `char*`. So the index operator subtracts one from the address, and dereferences it.

Answer (score 2):

`init()` returns a pointer to `a1[1]`. `o.init()[-1];` subtracts 1 from that pointer (so, you get a pointer to `a1[0]`) and dereferences it and you get `a1[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

init returns a char* so init()[-1] will just take the pointer one char backwards in the memory.

Imagine it like:

```
char* arr = o.init();
```

and then:

```
arr--;
```

As you can see, your function returns the array+1, so in order to take 'a', or rather the first value, you'll have to go one step backwards